# How can I convert Redux toolkit reducers In react

Tags: reactjs, redux

I've started to learn Redux with React, I got stuck in a part of my project which is an E-commerce store that when the user clicks on add to cart I want to update the quantity and add the article to the bag. I've implemented Redux for other functionalities but I found a solution for my problem with ReduxToolkit which I didn't learn yet

How can I convert this code written with a redux toolkit to Redux?

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: "cart",
  initialState: {
    products: [],
    quantity: 0,
    total: 0,
  },
  reducers: {
    addProduct: (state, action) => {
      state.quantity += 1;
      state.products.push(action.payload);
      state.total += action.payload.price * action.payload.quantity;
    },
  },
});

export const { addProduct } = cartSlice.actions;
export default cartSlice.reducer;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your current store is created in such a way:

```
const rootReducer=combineReducers({
          firstFunctionality:firstFunctionalityReducer,
          secondFunctionality:secondFunctionalityReducer,
          ... })
```

Now you want to create a new functionality like cart,

first you create the initial state:

```
const initialState={
    products: [],
    quantity: 0,
    total: 0,
  }
```

Now the reducer :

```
const cartReducer=(state=initialState,action)=>{

         switch (action.type) {
             case "addProduct":return {...state,
                                      quantity:state.quantity+1,
                                      products:[...state.products,action.payload],                                 
                                      total:action.payload.price*action.payload.quantity;
             
             case "default":return state}
             }
```

Now we use this new reducer:

```
const rootReducer=combineReducers({
          firstFunctionality:firstFunctionalityReducer,
          secondFunctionality:secondFunctionalityReducer,
          cartFunctionality:cartReducer
          ... })
```

Now whenever you need want to add a product you dispatch this action:

```
const addProductAction=(product)=>({type:"addProduct",payload:product})
```

one last thing is how you dispatch actions and use the state. which can be achieved by either useSelector and useDispatch hooks, or `mapDispatchToProps` and `mapStateToProps` and `connect` HOC.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but the code isn't working because there is no action function created in the solution that you've provided? what do you think